# Is it possible to read source code of a program compiled with microsoft visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction, decompiling, decompiler

I know there are tools for decompiling C# programs. Is using microsoft visual c++ make the code vulnerable for reverse engineering ?

What is the best tool and best programming language for hiding source code ? Or is there any ?

Comment: It is possible to reverse engg any code if the binary generated from the code is available, just the factor to consider is how much time will be needed to do so.

Comment: Code can still be reverse engineered if compiled from C++, but it is a lot more work than with C# or something similar.

Comment: You need to specify what you are trying to "hide". If you don't want people to extract your proprietary libraries/code and use them in other software, then compiling in C++ will definitely help. If you are trying to prevent your software from being cracked/hacked, then no language will really help. It will just be a cat and mouse game with the crackers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Microsoft C++ compiles to machine code.

While an extremely smart disassembler may be able to generate C++ code from the machine code, there's no way to ensure the generated code would match the original source code.

Comment: I don't think OPs actual intent in asking the Q is to reverse engg the binary to get the *exact* same source code, but the intent seems to be reverse engg to get a source code from the binary.

Comment: The title was "read source code of a program..." That suggested to me he was asking about seeing the source code used to build the program.

Comment: +1... But you you read in title too much you can also read it as "If I have source that can also be compiled with MSVC, can I still read it?" :)